# android, finding related words (not autocomplete)

Tags: android, dictionary, search-suggestion

When I type "Goat" my keyboard gives me a suggestion of the next word being "cheese", "milk" maybe more. These things are related and I am using a stock keyboard on my Nexus 4.

What API suggests that? I want to be able to store contextual words related to what a user typed in.

My first hunch is the UserDictionary api

[image]

Comment: Afaik, that's a feature of the keyboard, not an API.

Comment: I think [this file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/SuggestedWords.java) from the AOSP will help you to understand how word suggestions work.

Comment: Remove autosuggestion feature, if you don't want to see suggestions, but if you remove this, you will not get any suggestions any more.

Comment: @BetteDevine I want to access the suggestions programmatically

Comment: @stefan ah the Completion Info api